# Mapscript circular import error in Python inside Docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, dockerfile, mapserver

I have a simple flask app and I am trying to run in Docker

```
import mapscript
from flask import Flask
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
port = 5000

@app.route("/hello")
def geocoder():


    epsg = mapscript.pointObj(1, 1)
    return json.dumps(epsg)

    test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=port)
```

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python

WORKDIR /opt/demo/
COPY /app .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT python test.py
```

But I get the following error when I run `docker run -p 5000:5000 test:latest`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/demo/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mapscript
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mapscript/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .mapscript import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mapscript/mapscript.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _mapscript
ImportError: cannot import name '_mapscript' from partially initialized module 'mapscript' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mapscript/__init__.py)
```

This happens only when I have the Python VENV activated when running outside Docker but I don't know why I am getting this error inside Docker.